# Identities for $\cosh x + i\sinh x$

Tags: complex-analysis

In my research, an equation of the form $\cosh x + i\sinh x$ appears to show up. Expanding these terms by their definitions didn't provide any obvious way to express this as $e^{iz}$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you give more context as to how this expression came up in your research? (It's not an equation without an equality).

Comment: note that $\cosh x =\cos ix$ while $\sinh x=-i\sin ix$ so $\cosh x + i\sinh x=\cos ix+\sin ix$ and you can use the addition formula to make it $\sqrt 2 \cos (ix-\pi/4)$ for example but not sure if that is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\cosh(x)=\cos(ix),\,\sinh(x)=-i\sin(ix)$$So you've got: $$\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)$$You can't reduce that to $e^{iz}$ for any clever choice of $z$.

As a side-note you might be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number). Then $e^{jx}=\cosh(x)+j\sinh(x)$, but $j$ has a different meaning.